# doing class initialization using properties

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning iOS programming, so please bear with me.
Imagine I have a class in which I want to just have a *simple* `init` method (no params) and 
initialization of my instance variables I want to be done via properties.
For example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{

}
@property (nonatomic) SomeClass1 *p1;
@property (nonatomic) SomeClass2 *p2;
@property (nonatomic) SomeClass3 *p3;
```

As I mentioned I have a simple `init`, no parameters. Nothing, I don't even implement it, it is inherited from NSObject.
So, now, if someone wants to initialize `p1,p2,p3` variables of `MyClass` object, can't there be such problematic situations, when someone sets:

```
1. MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
2. [[object p1] doSomething];
```

where the 2nd line will raise an exception, because there was no for example `object.p1 = [[SomeClass1 alloc] init]` call before it?

Comment: In most languages it would raise an exception but in objective-c it will not raise an exception and there are many places where the coding style relies on this. "doSomething" is not a "method", it is a "message". One of the reasons it's called a "message" is because it is not guaranteed to run the method you asked to be run. It might run a different method or run no method at all. If you send a message to nil, it will run no method at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't raise an exception, because in Objective-C a method call on a `nil` object pointer is a no-op -- nothing happens. This is different from C++ where calling an instance method on a `NULL` pointer would cause a crash.

This actually turns out to be pretty useful, because it means you can chain method calls without having to worry that an intermediate method returns `nil`. Like this:

```
[[[[object p1] doSomething] doSomethingElse] doAnotherThing];
```

If messaging a `nil` object crashed or raised an exception, you would have to check the result of each of those four method calls in order to be safe.

For what it's worth, in general, if your object needs a valid value for `p1` in order to work correctly or be useful, it makes sense to make that object a parameter to the `-init` method.

Comment: ipmcc, and if calling an alloc/init method on an instance variable is required before it can be used, can the user do it using the property? e.g., `object1.p1 = [[SomeClass1 alloc] init]` -- and then use `object1.p1` afterwards with no problems...e.g., like `object.p1 = SomeValue;`

Comment: Sure. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: >>"For what it's worth, in general, if your object needs a valid value for p1 in order to work correctly or be useful, it makes sense to make that object a parameter to the -init method."
Or maybe it does not need some value but it just needs to be allocated, then I can simply just call an alloc/init in the `init` method for that instance variable right ...

Comment: Sure, if having that value is optional, then it's fine to do it later.